# Android failed to connect to camera service

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build a simple app that launches the camera app and allows me to take a picture and save it to the device but I keep getting this error.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    Preview preview;
    private Camera camera;
    private int cameraId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback;

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        preview = new Preview(this, (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView));
        preview.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main)).addView(preview);
        preview.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback()
        {
            public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data,
                                       final Camera camera)
            {
                new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
                resetCam();
                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
            }
        };

        preview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                if(camera != null)
                {
                    camera.takePicture(null,
                                       // ShutterCallback shutter
                                       null,
                                       // PictureCallback raw,
                                       null,
                                       // PictureCallback postview,
                                       jpegCallback); // PictureCallback jpeg);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        getCamera(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK);

        if(camera != null)
        {
            camera.startPreview();
            preview.setCamera(camera);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        if(camera != null)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
            preview.setCamera(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }

        super.onPause();
    }

    private void getCamera(final int desiredCamera)
    {
        if(!getPackageManager()
            .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        }
        else
        {
            cameraId = findCamera(desiredCamera);

            if(cameraId < 0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Camera no found.",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG, Integer.toString(cameraId));
                camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            }
        }
    }

    private int findCamera(final int desiredCamera)
    {
        final int numberOfCameras;
        int       cameraId;

        numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        cameraId        = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++)
        {
            final CameraInfo info;

            info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);

            if(info.facing == desiredCamera)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "Camera found");
                cameraId = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        return (cameraId);
    }

    private void resetCam()
    {
        camera.startPreview();
        preview.setCamera(camera);
    }

    private void refreshGallery(final File file)
    {
        final Intent mediaScanIntent;

        mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

    private class SaveImageTask
        extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final byte[]... data)
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream;
            final File       sdCard;
            final File       dir;
            final String     fileName;
            final File       outFile;

            sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            dir    = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
            dir.mkdirs();

            fileName  = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            outFile   = new File(dir, fileName);
            outStream = null;

            try
            {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
                outStream.write(data[0]);
                outStream.flush();

                Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());
                refreshGallery(outFile);
            }
            catch(final FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "File not found", ex);
            }
            catch(final IOException ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "IOException", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                try
                {
                    if(outStream != null)
                    {
                        outStream.close();
                    }
                }
                catch(final IOException ex)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException", ex);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Preview

```
class Preview
    extends ViewGroup
    implements Callback
{
    private final String TAG = Preview.class.getName();
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private Camera.Size previewSize;
    private List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera camera;

    Preview(final Context     context,
            final SurfaceView sv)
    {
        super(context);

        surfaceView = sv;
        holder      = surfaceView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera)
    {
        this.camera = camera;

        if(this.camera != null)
        {
            final Camera.Parameters params;
            final List<String>      focusModes;

            supportedPreviewSizes = this.camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            requestLayout();

            params     = this.camera.getParameters();
            focusModes = params.getSupportedFocusModes();

            if(focusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO))
            {
                params.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
                this.camera.setParameters(params);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec,
                             final int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        // We purposely disregard child measurements because act as a
        // wrapper to a SurfaceView that centers the camera preview instead
        // of stretching it.
        final int width;
        final int height;

        width  = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        height = resolveSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);

        if(supportedPreviewSizes != null)
        {
            previewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed,
                            int l,
                            int t,
                            int r,
                            int b)
    {
        if (changed && getChildCount() > 0)
        {
            final View child = getChildAt(0);

            final int width = r - l;
            final int height = b - t;

            int previewWidth = width;
            int previewHeight = height;

            if (previewSize != null)
            {
                previewWidth = previewSize.width;
                previewHeight = previewSize.height;
            }

            // Center the child SurfaceView within the parent.
            if (width * previewHeight > height * previewWidth)
            {
                final int scaledChildWidth = previewWidth * height / previewHeight;
                child.layout((width - scaledChildWidth) / 2, 0,
                             (width + scaledChildWidth) / 2, height);
            }
            else
            {
                final int scaledChildHeight = previewHeight * width / previewWidth;
                child.layout(0, (height - scaledChildHeight) / 2,
                             width, (height + scaledChildHeight) / 2);
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        try
        {
            if(camera != null)
            {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException caused by setPreviewDisplay()", exception);
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        if(camera != null)
        {
            camera.stopPreview();
        }
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes,
                                              int w,
                                              int h)
    {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) w / h;
        if (sizes == null) return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        // Try to find an size match aspect ratio and size
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes)
        {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        // Cannot find the one match the aspect ratio, ignore the requirement
        if (optimalSize == null)
        {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes)
            {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff)
                {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format,
                               int width,
                               int height)
    {
        if(camera != null)
        {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);
            requestLayout();

            camera.setParameters(parameters);
            camera.startPreview();
        }
    }
```